# Linear Transformation Problem Given 3 transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

can anyone help me get started with this question. Right now I am guessing and checking which is not efficient. I figured out out that the transformation is (?,?,x-y-z) so far

> Let $T:\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R^3$ be a linear transformation such that $T(1,1,1)=(2,0,-1)$,  $T(0,-1,2)=(3,2,-1)$ and $T(1,0,1)=(1,1,0)$. What is $T(2,1,0)$?

Original link:
http://tinypic.com/r/2mg37dl/5

Comment: Protip: make use of information that you're given before resorting to random guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
Write $(2,1,0)$ as a linear combination of $(1,1,1),(0,-1,2)$ and $(1,0,1)$ and then make use of the fact that $T$ *is a linear transformation*.

Comment: ok so after the linear combination i got x1=0 x2=-1 x3=2. What should i do afterwards?

Comment: @user123204 Good! So you found $-1\cdot(0,-1,2)+2\cdot(1,0,1)=(2,0,1)$. Apply $T$ to both sides and you have your answer.

Comment: got it its -1,0,1 thanks alot!